# SCRIPT5007:unable to get the property 'widget' of undefined or null reference

Tags: dojo, internet-explorer-9

I'm using dojo-release-1.6.1, facing the mentioned issue when I'm trying my application in IE9. Anybody suggests what could be the reason for the issue. It's working fine in IE8.
In my page I'm using this piece of code:

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox"); 
dojo.require("dojox.widget.Calendar");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not shure if dojos Version 1.6.1 supports the IE9.
It looks like only 1,7+ can handle IE9.

Check this out: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/releasenotes/1.6.html#releasenotes-1-6

Regards